# Unable to create kubernetes cluster on openstack

Tags: kubernetes

ERROR: The template version is invalid: Unknown version (heat_template_version: 2016-10-14). Should be one of: 2012-12-12, 2013-05-23, 2010-09-09

Answer (score 1):

Best way of creating kubernetes cluster on openstack is, by using **Magnum**

**Magnum** is a OpenStack project which allows to create COE on a fly

Please refer this link for further details:

https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Magnum